# Having issues with map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to build an ecommerce website and getting an error:
products.map is not a function
I am using Visual Studio

```
import styled from "styled-components";
import ProductBox from "ProductBox";

const StyledProductsGrid = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
  @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
`;

export default function ProductsGrid({products}) {
  return (
    <StyledProductsGrid>
      {products?.length > 0 && products.map(product => (
        <ProductBox key={product._id} {...product} />
      ))}
    </StyledProductsGrid>
  );
}
```

Been trying to follow along with a tutorial to get experience in code, while following along their code works but for some reason I am getting this error and not sure where to go or what to do about it.

Comment: If `products.map` is not a function then `products` is not an array.  What is it?  Why do you expect it to be an array?

Comment: As always, share *all* relevant code. What is  ```products``` and where is it defined?

Comment: Either place a breakpoint at the `return` or log the value of `products` to the console. The following should print true, if `products` is an array, `console.log(Array.isArray(products))`. Make sure that an array is being passed to the component i.e. `<ProductsGrid products={[...]} />` If you used `PropTypes`, JSDoc, or even TypeScript, issues like these would be caught within the IDE.

Comment: Add more information, send a log of the products array

Comment: @Robert Thank you, I had it defined elsewhere but had it misspelled and that caused the issue I was receiving! After looking at where I had it defined at I realized I was supposed to have it set to product instead of products